# R POSIXct cannot be used in sql query

Tags: r, posix

I have a connection that brings data from slq with format datetime. I need to keep tre time part too.

```
head(llamMitUadm$responseTime)
[1] "2014-10-07 08:00:33.780" "2014-10-07 08:01:17.813" "2014-10-07 08:01:19.450"
[4] "2014-10-07 08:01:34.773" "2014-10-07 08:01:54.950" "2014-10-07 08:02:08.607"

> class(llamMitUadm$responseTime)
[1] "character"
```

Then I convert it to datetime:

```
llamMitUadm$responseTime1<-strptime(llamMitUadm$responseTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

> class(llamMitUadm$responseTime1)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"

> head(llamMitUadm$responseTime1)
[1] "2014-10-07 08:00:33 ART" "2014-10-07 08:01:17 ART" "2014-10-07 08:01:19 ART"
[4] "2014-10-07 08:01:34 ART" "2014-10-07 08:01:54 ART" "2014-10-07 08:02:08 ART"
```

The I need to do a sql query and I get the following error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'
```

I read that this is related to POSIXt format. How can I keep the datime and be able to perform the query?

Altought I know is not related to the query, I added a reproducible example:

```
data<-data.frame(date=c("2014-10-07 08:00:33.780","2014-10-07 08:01:17.813","2014-10-07 08:01:19.450"))


> class(data$date)
[1] "factor"

 data$date<-as.character(data$date)
> class(data$date)
[1] "character"


 data$date1<-strptime(data$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    > class(data$date1)
    [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

 library(sqldf)
> sqldf("Select * from data")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'
```

Comment: So you want us to help you debug a sql query that you don't bother to include in your question? That's....ambitious.

Comment: @joran I read that the problem is related with the class POSIX, the query is ok.

Comment: <shrug> I was all set to try to help, but if you refuse to provide even the most basic information, I'll just do something else.

Comment: @joran, please see the edition

Comment: Ah...you're using **sqldf**. Never put POSIXlt variables in data frames. Use POSIXct instead.

Comment: how can I convert it to POSIXct?

Comment: Please provide a minimal self contained example.  That means others can simply copy the code from your question and paste it into their session and they will see what you see.  For input show the result of `dput(x)` where `x` is the input so that it is reproducible -- don't just print it out.  Also if it has nothing to do with databases pose the question in such a way that its independent of them.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXlt is a list, so cannot ve stored in a data frame. I solved it with:

```
as.POSIXct(llamMitUadm$responseTime)
```